# Why I'm getting the error "Must provide query string." express-graphql?

Tags: javascript, html, schema, graphql, express-graphql

I'm beginning with graphql on express. I'm getting the error "Must provide query string." when I access to the route for it.

It's an express app. Here is my app.js

```js
var createError   = require('http-errors');  
var express       = require('express');  
var path          = require('path');  
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');  
var logger        = require('morgan');  
let bodyParser    = require('body-parser');  
var cors          = require('cors');  
    
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');  
const MySchema    = require('./schema/schema');  

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: MySchema,
  graphiql: true,
}));
```

And my shema is:

```js
const graphql = require('graphql');
const {
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLList
} = graphql;


//MODELS FROM MONGOOSE
const Entidad = require('../models/entidad');


//TYPES GRAPHQL
const EntidadType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Entidad',
    fields : () => ({
        id      : {type : GraphQLString},
        nombre  : {type : GraphQLString},
        created_at : { type : GraphQLString},
        updated_at : { type : GraphQLString},
    })
});

//ROOT QUERY
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name : 'RootQueryType',
    fields : {
        entidad : {
            type: EntidadType,
            args: {id:{type: GraphQLString}},
            resolve(parent, args){
                //code to get data from db
                return Entidad.findById(args.id);
            }
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
});
```

I don't know why I'm getting the error when open graphiql.

I test other examples and give me the same error, maybe there is some part that I missed....

Some idea?

Comment: Are you using other middleware on your server? If so, it would be helpful to see that  code as well, since middleware like `body-parser` can mess with the logic in `express-graphql`'s middleware.

Comment: Ok I updated the post, now you can see middlewares. I'm using body-parser

Comment: Now I comment the line app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); and I see the root query on Documentation explorer but now I'm getting the error

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 29,
          "column": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Hello @DanielRearden,
I'm facing the same error when I try to access graphql with AWS lambda function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I commented the line of body-parser and I fix the problem, the other problem is because I don't have a rootValue into the route of graphql. I tested the queries and it's all ok. Thanks.